# How to get a number from an array?

Tags: java, arrays

question:
    Suppose this is the number in my array `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}`
    and each number is a position like ::
    `1=1 ,2=2 , 3=3,  4=4,  5=5,  6=6,  7=7,  8=8`

It is not an array position just the number position. Now i want to remove the number in odd position then it becomes

```
2,4,6,8 :: 2=1, 4=2,  6=3,  8=4,
```

Now again i want to remove from the odd position so it becomes `4,8 :: 4=1,  8=2`

Now the answer is `8` so how to get this `8`

Code:

```
int [] arr = new int [] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}; //I am taking certain number in array   
System.out.println("Elements of given array present on even position:"); 
for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i = i+2) {   
          System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

must get the value as 8 but in output i get:

```
2 
2
2
2
4
4
4
4
```

and so on

Comment: look into using the modulus operator

Comment: So in short you want to have the last position of the array that is on an even index? Because that is what all this "removing odds" will always lead to.

Comment: You need a modulo operator (`%`) to identify numbers in odd positions and a `while` loop (iterate `while array.length >= 2`)

Comment: Note : you can also do it without a modulo if you use a `for` loop where you increment the index by `2` instead of `1`.

Comment: In Java, array indexes start at 0.

Comment: i want the even position till there is last element in the array

Comment: @Nico238 i am not going through array position just considering it has 1=1 and so on

Comment: i wanted to do in for loops like nested for loop

Comment: So you want the number which is the greatest power of 2. (try to test arrays {1..10 },{1..20} ...)

Answer (score 0):

This will print out even numbers:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
 {   
      if (arr[i] % 2 == 0)
      {
          System.out.println(arr[i]);
      }
 }
```

If you want to remove the odd position elements from the array, then make a new one and use the above code to exclude odd elements like so:

```
ArrayList<Integer> newArr = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
 {   
      if (i % 2 == 0)
      {
          newArr.add(arr[i]);
      }
 }
```

Comment: sir 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 <- array now if for loop if i will get 2,4,6,8, now i have to again run the loop to get 4,8 and then again i have to run to get 8 how to get 8

Comment: i don't want to remove just want to print the element in even position till there is single digit

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
   if(i % 2 == 0){ //if divide by 2 gives remainder 0 it is even
   list.add(arr[i]);
   }
}
arr=list.toArray();//get the array version of the list
```

Then you could put it in a while loop to do it until there is only one left.

```
int [] arr = new int [] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
while(arr.length>1){
...
}
System.out.println(arr[0]);
```

Remember that we start counting at 0 so the first position(i=0) would even and the second position(i=1) would be uneven.

Final Code:

```
int [] arr = new int [] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
while(arr.length>1){
   ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

   for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
      if(i % 2 == 0){ //if divide by 2 gives remainder 0 it is even
      list.add(arr[i]);
      }
   }
   arr=list.toArray();//get the array version of the list
}
System.out.println(arr[0]);
```

Comment: you could, but then you would have to calculate the amount of times to run the code before hand. It's way easier with the while loop.

Comment: The while loops just executes the the code again and again until the array has one item left.

Comment: sorry i am not getting the single number even using while

Comment: Have you put the for loop bit inside the while loop?

Comment: I still dont understand why you don't just take the last element

Comment: incompatible type for converting int to toArray

Comment: My code it quite rough, use it as sudo code rather that copy pasting directly.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you

```
int [] arr = new int [] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12}; //I am taking certain
        System.out.println("Elements of given array present on even position:");
        int counter=2;
        while(counter<=arr.length){
            counter*=2;
        }
        System.out.println(arr[(counter/2)-1]);
```

Let me know if this works

Comment: i am not getting output as if i take input of arrays till 8

Comment: @SwagnashThor Should be fine now. Please check and let me know

Comment: no sir if i take element of arr from 1-8 it cannot bring a single element in last

Comment: Well, as per my previous answer, i was trying to show you how the output was being derived without using another array but since you want a single output, this code snippet now prints a single output for your question. Let me know if this works for your case.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, you want the greatest power of 2 :

```
int max=0;
for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
   int pos = arr[i];
   if((pos & (pos-1)) == 0) { // check if pos is a power of 2
      max =java.lang.Math.max(max, pos);
   }
}
System.out.println(max)
```

if arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}; => output 8

if arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} => output 8

if arr = {1,2,3,...,20} => output 16

Comment: your are giving me highest element in the array i want the even position element in the array and for eg 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 here the i=1 to get  even numbers 2,4,6,8 then again j=1 then we get 4,8 and again k=1 we get 8  i want like this but how to get into loops??